# OpenCL - Atomic operation with double - works until limit

Tags: c, opencl, atomic, reduction

Following this [link](http://suhorukov.blogspot.fr/2011/12/opencl-11-atomic-operations-on-floating.html), I try to implement an atomic function that computes the sum of an array of double, so I implemented my own `atom_add` function (for double).

Here's the kernel code used:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64: enable
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_int64_base_atomics : enable

void atom_add_double(__global double *val, double delta)
{
  union {
  double f;
  ulong  i;
  } old, new;

  do
  {
   old.f = *val;
   new.f = old.f + delta;
  } 
  while (atom_cmpxchg((volatile __global ulong *)val, old.i, new.i) != old.i);

}  

__kernel void sumGPU ( __global const double *input, 
               __global double *finalSum
                 )
{
  // Index of current workItem
  uint gid = get_global_id(0);

  // Init sum
  *finalSum = 0.0;

  // Compute final sum 
  atom_add_double(finalSum, input[gid]);

}
```

My issue is that kernel codes generates good results until I reach roughly 100000 elements for size of `input` array.

Over this limit, the computation isn't valid any more (I can check the result easily because in my test case, I fill the input array by a loop `for(i=0;i<sizeArray;i++) input[i]=i+1;`, so the sum is equal to `sizeArray*(sizeArray+1)/2`).

Can I define and put a function like `atom_add_double` into the kernel code?

Comment: As I told you already, don't use atomics to reduce, and please don't use atomics that lock threads, they are even worse. Use a proper reduction code or CL 2.0 reduction functions. https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/work_group_reduce.html
We are talking about 10x performance penalty (at least) when using atomics vs proper parallel reduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*finalSum = 0.0;
```

is race condition for all in-flight threads. It is making result zero for my computer. Delete it, initialize it from host side. If your gpu is very good one, number of in-flight threads could be as high as 50000 maybe even more and each one hitting finalSum = 0.0 before any begins atomic function but when you pass that limit, 50001st (just a trivial number) thread re-initializes it to zero.

Then, sum of all elements is not equal to size*(size+1)/2 because it is starting from zero(zeroth element is zero) so it is actually

```
(size-1)*(size)/2
```

and is giving right results for my computer when I delete finalSum =0.0 from kernel.

Comment: good job by initializing finalSum from host code ! actually, I did input[i]=i+1 (I did  rectification in my question). thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

@huseyin answer is correct to fix the issue.

However, I can't resist to say **"Don't use atomics to reduce."**

And even worse atomics that lock in a while loop and access global data directly. We are probably talking about 10x performance hit, at least.

If you can, use [proper automatic reduction (CL 2.0+)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/work_group_reduce.html).

```
__kernel void sumGPU(__global const double *input, __global double *finalSum)
{
  // Index of current workItem
  uint gid = get_global_id(0);

  // Sum locally without atomics
  double sum = work_group_scan_inclusive_add(input[gid]);

  // Compute final sum using atomics
  // but it is even better if just store them in an array and do final sum in CPU
   // Only add the last one, since it contains the total sum
  if (get_local_id(0) == get_local_size(0) - 1) { 
    atom_add_double(finalSum, sum);
  }
}
```